# Replace numbers one by one with regex

Tags: regex

I have strings such as this:

```
"Query_string" : [ 1345.6423, 5656.5, 346.324, 880.0 ],
"Query_string" : [ 1345.6423, 5656.5, 346.324, 880.0 ],
"Query_string" : [ 1345.6423, 5656.5, 346.324, 880.0 ],
Random code 124253
String.....
```

I need to replace digits that have "query_string" in front of them to be zero, like so:

```
"Query_string" : [ 0000.0000, 0000.0, 000.000, 000.0 ],
```

But other stuff should stay in place, eg:

```
Random code 124253
```

I tried this:

```
(^\"Query\_string\"\s\:\s\[\s)|\d|(\s\]\,)
```

But it matches all digits, including "Random code 124253"

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ": loop
s/\("Query_string".*\)[1-9]/\10/
t loop" YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This sed expression replaces all non-zero digits on Query lines with 0:

```
 sed '/^"Query_string"/{s/[1-9]/0/g}' input
```

Another version:

```
sed '/^"Query_string"/!b;s/[1-9]/0/g' input
```

Still another:

```
sed '/^"Query_string"/s/[1-9]/0/g' input
```

Comment: This doesn't work under OSX sed.
sed: 1: "/^Query_string/{s/[1-9 ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Comment: Can you check the version I just added?

Comment: in front of them does not mean Starting by. meanwhile your sed is fine based on the sample

Comment: `sed '/^"Query_string"/s/[1-9]/0/g' input`
gives: `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`


`sed '/^"Query_string"/!b;s/[1-9]/0/g' input`
gives: `sed: 1: "/^"Query_string"/!b;s/ ...": undefined label ';s/[1-9]/0/g'`